# How can I draw arrows that radiate out of a sphere using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-arrows

This is the code that I am using for my sphere:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
\draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
\fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I draw arrows that radiate out of the sphere at even intervals, similar to the MS Paint picture I've included below?

[image: Sphere with arrows]

I only need to draw about eight arrows, just to show that molecules are diffusing out of the spherical object.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice (?) green diffusing molecule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
\shade[ball color=green] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
\draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
\fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\foreach \i in {0,45,...,315}
{
\begin{scope}[rotate=\i] 
\draw[-latex,thick] (2.1,0) -- (3,0);
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]